# Is there a word to describe a plausible but incorrect explanation?

Tags: single-word-requests, science, logic, rhetoric, rhetorical-devices

I'm thinking of something where somebody (with no malicious intention) offers a very plausible and scientific-sounding explanation (not a theory but something presented as a series of facts) such that nobody would even question it because it makes total sense. It is accepted as truth. However, if one actually did an experiment to test the explanation it is easily falsified, showing the explanation to be incorrect and that other factors must be responsible for the observed phenomenon.

Is there a word to describe such an explanation?

Comment: Are you talking about a theory that turns out to be proven wrong—or are you talking about a well-crafted deception (like a spy's cover story)?

Comment: [Specious](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/specious): Superficially plausible, but actually wrong.

Comment: Plausible but incorrect is distorted by *illusional* and by most of the other answers in this link, as there is no implication here of an attempt to deceive or be tricky, just an explanation that seems reasonable but is, or can be shown to be, incorrect. I don’t know a one-word synonym for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sophistry

1. a subtle, tricky, superficially plausible, but generally fallacious method of reasoning.
2. a false argument; sophism.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sophistry

Comment: This answer is already present in the duplicate.

Comment: Please explain what that means

Comment: The duplicate I've posted in comments already has the word 'sophistry'.

Comment: ah ok i see it now. Thanks